# Sharepoint JSOM: set_item() without update()

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm using SharePoint Javascript Object Model (JSOM). Can someone explain to me what `set_item()` does when `update()` is not called?

Below is some code to illustrate.

#### Boilerplate code to get the list items:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Employees');
var listItems = list.getItems("");

ctx.load(listItems, "Include(Name, Role)");
ctx.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
```

#### first set of commands

```
var first = listItems.getItemAtIndex(0);
var second = listItems.getItemAtIndex(1);

first.set_item("Role", "foo");
second.set_item("Role", "bar");

second.update(); // only call update on the second item
ctx.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
```

The actual network request to SharePoint contains two "SetFieldValue" methods with "foo" and "bar", and only one "Update" method for the second one. SharePoint only updated the second value with "bar".

#### second set of commands

```
first.update();
ctx.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
```

The second request contains only a single Update method. SharePoint did not update the first value with "foo".

#### Question

Why is the first item sent even though update was not called?

Clearly, when `first.update()` is called, the new value is not passed again - but I would at least assume that it would be staged in SharePoint, waiting for the `update()` - but that doesn't happen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Executing `update()` cues the backend to actively replace/add values to the stored object; `set_item()` passes the value and field to be updated to the server. Both are working as intended, but no actual change will occur to the stored information until you utilize `update()` explicitly. This may be in order to better utilize batch processing.

Comment: True, but why would a change log from `set_item` go over the network if there was no way (that I can see) to utilize it?

Comment: I would hazard that it's probably purely preparatory. It may also (and mind you I'm hypothesizing at this point) be useful in terms of asynchronous development.

Programmatically speaking, it's a very clear syntax to `set` `update` `execute`. This provides a convenient control flow; additionally, you can set multiple items to queue up for the `update()` method.

Comment: I tried the latter - it didn't work. Which was the reason it puzzled me.

Comment: Although, I see what you're saying regarding the unnecessary network traffic.

However, the asynchronous nature of the program may require you to set those items into the backend queue, and then execute the update method later through an asynchronous chain.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, by calling calling `update` at a later point, and that had not effect.

Comment: We could always test to see how long the value persists; maybe setting a timer job to execute `update()` at given intervals to see if `update()` needs to be sent within a specific timeframe?

Comment: I'll spend some time testing this tomorrow. I'll be curious to see whether or not I can create a control flow emulating this, because I can think of a couple reasons it occurs, and I'd like to emulate the ones that are wrong. But, offhand:
- Potential batch processing benefits
- Asynchronous operations elsewhere (not `executeQueryAsync()`)
- Unintended side-effect

There are some oddities within the Sharepoint API and programmatic access to the data structure. It may just be something that needs revision, but documentation is a little lacking on the MSDN site.